# How do I append to all string values inside a struct?

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct defined in `fruits.go`

```
package domain

type AppleImages struct {
    Front string `json:"frontImage"`
    Back  string `json:"backImage"`
    Top   string `json:"topImage"`
}
```

And I defined the same in `process.go` (which returns this data to the handler). This definition is only for demonstration purposes since I'm getting values from the database using gorm so we cannot append the required URL here.

```
package process

func getApple() (apple domain.Apple){
    apple = domain.Apple{
        Front: "front-image.png"
        Back: "back-image.png"
        Top: "top-image.png"
    }
    return
}
```

For my output is want to return

```
{
    frontImage: "https://www.example.com/front-image.png",
    backImage: "https://www.example.com/back-image.png",
    topImage: "https://www.example.com/top-image.png",
}
```

**I don't want to manually add `https://www.example.com/` to each of the images in the struct.**

Is there a way of parsing through the struct and automatically appending this string to all existing values?

Comment: Make a function to represent with domain name any struct attribute.

Comment: @Зелёный can you please elaborate?

Comment: The most obvious approach would be to write a function that takes a pointer to the struct and a prefix, modifies the struct's fields with the prefix and exits, you'd then call this function manually. Alternatively gorm provides support for hooks, in this case the `AfterFind` method, which if implemented on the target type, will be invoked automatically which avoids having to call the func manually in every place where the functionality is needed. Lastly, you could use the `reflect` package to iterate over the fields of a struct and modify them by prefixing them with a given input.

Comment: ... or you could utilize the `json.Marshaler` interface, either by implementing it directly on the `AppleImages` type, or if you need to parameterize the prefix you could have the marshaler interface be implemented by a wrapper that takes as a prameter, besides the value to be marshaled, the prefix to be prepended.

Comment: @mkopriva I ended up implementing it using the `reflect` package. But thanks a lot for the alternatives :) I'll check them out and see which method feels the most efficient.

Comment: @VarunShridhar keep in my that for the problem presented as is, using `reflect` is overkill *in my opinion*. It may be that your actual use case does warrant the use of `reflect` but it's also possible that it doesn't. Just make sure your decision to use `reflect` can stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: @mkopriva can you please add your comments as an answer so I can accept it? I feel it was the most rounded of all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Use gorm `AfterFind` hook. Every time after load data from database gorm call `AfterFind` and your data will be updated for `Apple` model. Then you don't need to manually do it after every time fetching from the database.

```
func (u *Apple) AfterFind() (err error) {
  u.Front= "https://www.example.com/"+ u.Front
  u.Back= "https://www.example.com/"+ u.Back
  u.Top= "https://www.example.com/"+ u.Top
  return
}
```

See details [here](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html#Querying-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of parsing through the struct and automatically appending this string to all existing values?

No.

> I don't want to manually add https://www.example.com/ to each of the images in the struct.

Go provides no magic for thing to happen without you programming it. You must do this "manually".

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reflect` to add a prefix for each filed in the struct.
See details [here](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect?tab=doc).

```golang
func getApple() (apple domain.Apple) {
    apple = domain.Apple{
        Front: "front-image.png",
        Back:  "back-image.png",
        Top:   "top-image.png",
    }
    addURL(&apple, "https://www.example.com/")
    //fmt.Println(apple)
    return
}

func addURL(apple *domain.Apple, url string) {
    structValue := reflect.ValueOf(apple).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < structValue.NumField(); i++ {
        fieldValue := structValue.Field(i)

        // skip non-string field
        if fieldValue.Type().Kind() != reflect.String {
            continue
        }

        structValue.Field(i).SetString(url + fieldValue.String())
    }
}
```